# How to change the character after the cursor?

Tags: key-bindings

Is there a key binding to change a single character, i.e., delete character and enter insert mode? This would be analogous to `cw` (change word). For example, `cx` would seem to be logical.

Obviously a macro can be created to do this:

```
qx`xi`q
```

... but a two character macro does not have much logic.

Answer (score 9):

Yup it's `s` in normal mode. See [`:h s`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#s):

```
["x]s           Delete [count] characters [into register x] and start
                insert (s stands for Substitute).  Synonym for "cl"
                (not linewise).
```

Comment: Also, `S` is a synonym for `cc`.

Answer (score 6):

First off, Statox's answer is great. Use `s`. But, I have a couple more thoughts beyond the answer that are a little more in depth than a comment is worth.

Even if we didn't have the 's' command, there is already a way to do this! Think about it. We have the command `change + motion`. The "motion" is a single character. So it's just `cl`. As far as I'm concerned, the `s` command is just a synonym for `cl`.

Also, if we didn't have either of these features, there is a much more sensible way to implement them. Rather than doing

```
qx`xi`q
```

Which would be a pain to record, and a pain to type `@x` whenever you want this, you could just do

```
nnoremap cx xi
```

Comment: It is actually the same, if you do :h s it says "synonym for "cl".